# Why does "scale_x_discrete" screw up the zoom on my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to plot my data in R and trying to manually relabel the x axis keeps creating weird extra space on either side of the plot (see pictures).

Here's my code:

```
ACL_data_frame <- data.frame(ACLdata, Pre_PHQ_Score, Post_PHQ_Score)
colnames(ACL_data_frame)[c(328:329)] <- c("PHQ.1", "PHQ.2")
ACL_data_frame_long <- reshape(ACL_data_frame, direction="long", varying=328:329, sep=".")
ACL_data_frame_long$Condition <- factor(ACL_data_frame_long$Condition)
ggplot(data = ACL_data_frame_long, aes(x = time, y = PHQ, linetype = Condition)) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", size=1.25) +
  labs(x="Time", y="Depression (PHQ-9)") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2"),
                  labels=c("Pre", "Post")) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name="Condition",
                       breaks=c("1", "2"),
                       labels=c("Control", "Intervention"))
```

The relevant columns in my data basically look like this (but longer):

| time | PHQ | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6666667 | 1 |
| 1 | 1.1111111 | 2 |
| 2 | 0.7777778 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.3333333 | 1 |

Does anyone know how to get rid of the weird space on either side of the plot (see pics)? I tried xlim but that gives an error. Removing the scale_x_discrete also fixes it, but then I can't figure out another way to label the x axis correctly (i.e., there are only 2 timepoints so having labels for Time 1.25, Time 1.5, etc doesn't make sense, they need to just be labeled "Pre" and "Post")

[Plot using scale_x_discrete, with correct x axis labels but incorrect margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pshNV.png)

[Plot without scale_x_discrete, with correct margins but incorrect x axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9o8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

As your `time` column is a numeric you get a continuous scale by default. Therefore, to set the breaks and labels use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("Pre", "Post"))`. Adding `scale_x_discrete` will switch to a discrete scale which by default adds an expansion of `.6` to the lower and the upper end of the scale. In contrast, `scale_x_continuous` adds an expansion of 5% of the data range to the lower and the upper end of the scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = ACL_data_frame_long, aes(x = time, y = PHQ, linetype = Condition)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", size = 1.25) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Depression (PHQ-9)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("Pre", "Post")) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(
    name = "Condition",
    breaks = c("1", "2"),
    labels = c("Control", "Intervention")
  )
```

[image]